# web3.eth.accounts.create method doesn't actually create new account

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I try to create an eth account via RPC in private network.

What I have done so far are:

1. launch geth node and create private network.
2. create simple javascript program using web3 1.0.0, typescript
3. run and get result as below but the account isn't created

Code:

```
const result = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(senderId, senderPassword, duration)
if (result === true) {
    // const newAccountResult = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount('password')
    const newAccountResult = await web3.eth.accounts.create('user01')
    console.log(newAccountResult)
}
```

Result:

`web3.eth.accounts.create` returns the following result

```
{ address: '0xf10105f862C1cB10550F4EeB38697308c7A290Fc',
  privateKey: '0x5cba6b397fc8a96d006988388553ec17a000f7da9783d906979a2e1c482e7fcb',
  signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt] }
```

But `web3.eth.getAccounts` method returns only 1 account.

```
[ '0xaf0034c41928Db81E570061c58c249f61CFF57f2' ]
```

Seems `web3.eth.accounts.create` method has succeeded as the result includes account address and private key.
But I don't understand why `web3.eth.getAccounts` method doesn't include the created account.

I also checked geth via console, the result is same.

```
> eth.accounts
["0xaf0034c41928db81e570061c58c249f61cff57f2"]
```

And `eth.personal.newAccount` didn't work.
Do I need to do something after `web3.eth.accounts.create`?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got it right, `web.eth.accounts.create` is a way to create accounts without storing them on the local node, so its basically a way to get a valid keypair on-the-fly without storing anything on the keystore)

`web3.eth.personal.newAccount()` should be availabel if you have the personal-API activated on your geth node (which is default behavior for ganache, with `geth` you need to activate it via `geth --dev/testnet --rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,personal` (note: of course you should be very careful with allowing personal-API on mainnet, make sure that RPC access is restricted so only you/privileged users can access it)

```
(async () => {
    let newAccount = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount();
    console.log(newAccount);
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
})();
```

Should give something like

```
0xb71DCf0191E2B90efCD2638781DE40797895De66
[
    ...
'0xb71DCf0191E2B90efCD2638781DE40797895De66' ]
```

Refs https://medium.com/@andthentherewere0/should-i-use-web3-eth-accounts-or-web3-eth-personal-for-account-creation-15eded74d0eb

Comment: I tried `newAccount` method before and failed somehow but tried it again then succeeded! Thanks!